# sorting array indices by the array values

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to write a function that takes array like this [4,7,2,1,9]
then return another array like this

```
[4,1,0,2,3]// the sorted indices descending for the input array values
```

I've tried this code but it isn't working properly, I want to hepl me for writing a function that sort array like this with minimum cost

```
 public void solution(int[] D)
 {
    int[] sorted = new int[D.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < D.Length; i++)
    {
        int ind = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < D.Length; j++)
        {
            if (D[j] > D[i] ) //&&
            {
                ind = j;
            }
        }
        sorted[i] = ind;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.Sort` allows you to pass a second array:

```
var data = new[] { 4, 7, 2, 1, 9 };
var indices = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Array.Sort( data, indices );
```

If you need it in descending order, use `Array.Reverse` or pass it an `IComparer` that swaps the order:

```
class ReverseSort : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare( int x, int y )
    {
        return y.CompareTo( x );
    }
}

Array.Sort( data, indices, new ReverseSort() );
```

Unfortunately `Array.Sort` doesn't have a nice overload that takes two arrays + a delegate like the other overloads do.